# Symbolic link to directory

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm trying to create a shortcut/link to a folder in a shared partition. 
However the following code generates a broken link:

```
ln -s $PWD ~/Desktop/
```

Any ideas. I'm sure in 18.04 I just did a right click and it created a shortcut the same as Windows! I at least know I didn't have to search forums for the answer.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: ‘echo $PWD‘ output needed

Comment: I don't think the link is broken but incorrectly displayed in the file manager or on your desktop. I can see an unknown file in Thunar (I'm using xfce) which appears as the correct link after choosing `Reload` from the dropdown menu. But on my desktop the link is immediatly displayed correctly. You should check with `ls -l ~/Desktop` which should show the link correctly. For me this looks like a bug, most probably in the file manager.

Comment: @havon - The output of echo is just the file path
media/debo/SHARED I/fotos


I notice that when I run the code to create the link it actually creates 2 links -
One of which is to "SHARED" the other is to I/fotos
So it would seem the space might be causing the problem.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for your replies. The space was the problem. 
The link now works! Cheers